# how to access the result from mysql using a dynamically generated field name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with many rates named rate1, rate2, rate3 ....... I need to be able to access them by a dynamically created PHP variable eg:

```
$fieldname = "rate". "2";
$cost = $qty * $mysqlresult->$fieldname;
```

I am sure there must be an answer already but have not been able to phrase the right question.

Comment: That should work as is. Please indicate what's not working about it.

Comment: if value of field is static then you can use for loop starting with 1 and < 3 for example for($i=1;$i<3;$i++) { $cost.$i = $qty * $mysqlreqult->$fieldname.$i; }

Comment: Thank you all for answering the question. I am embarrassed, the problem was I left the $ off $fieldname. eg  $cost = $qty * $mysqlresult->fieldname; I apologize for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

Without more info as to your specific problem, all I can provide is a simple solution as to how to format an SQL query in PHP where both the key and val are variables

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM ". DB_TABLE ." WHERE ". $myKey ." = ". $myValue;
```

If you expand your question and supporting info some more I can expand my answer further if this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

When your $mysqlresult is an Object, you can access the properties by using this:

```
$mysqlresult->{$fieldname}
```